# Get touch position while swiping

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

anyone is aware of a way to get the current touch position (not start or end position) while user is swiping?

Something like the

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.x);
}
```

but for UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Thanks,

Max

Comment: for that you have to use `PanGestureRecognizer`...

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer has `locationInView`

Comment: @Mountain Lion: Thanks, it works flawlessly. If you want post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PanGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)onDraggingLetter:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGR {
CGPoint translation = [panGR translationInView:baseView];

    if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    } else if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) { 
    }
    else if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` class only provides the starting point of the gesture and the direction. However the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` repeatedly calls it's associated action method and you can get the current location of the gesture (using `locationInView:`) each time.